# Laravel 4.1: View does not echo query even though controller passes correct json

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am following a tutorial on Laravel 4 but I am stuck at a specific point. I want to return a view showing the user with his photos. For this I have the following method in my controller:

```
    public function show($id)
{
    $user = User::whereId($id)->with('photo')->first();

    return View::make('authenticated.users.show', compact('user'));
}
```

If I return $user the json I am seeing in the browser seems to be perfectly correct.

However, if I try to display that in the show.blade.php view I am getting this error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id
```

The code I am using in my view is the following:

```
 <li>{{ $user->photo->id }}</li>
```

Its exactly as shown in the tutorial but it does not work out.

I would very much appreciate some help.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try {{ $user->photo()->id }}

Comment: hm this does not work either..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most like that you are using the `hasMany` relationship in your User model.  When using the `hasMany` relationship, it will return a [`Collection`](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Support.Collection.html) object, rather than your model itself.  Take a look at the API for the Collection object and you'll find many helpful methods.

What you should probably do is something like this.

```
foreach ($user->photo->all() as $photo)
{
    echo $photo;
}
```

Or, if your user only has one photo, then change your relationship in the User model to `hasOne`.  Then you can use it as you are now.

```
echo $user->photo;
```

Comment: { echo $photo; } { echo $photo; } { echo $photo; } { echo $photo; }

Comment: This is what I get as a result. Notice: The user has 4 photos so it has to do anything with the photos.

Comment: This is what I am using now.

@foreach ($user->photo->all() as $photo)
{
    {{ $photo->id }}
}

What I get as a output is this:{ 1} { 3} { 7} { 8}